# How to I remove the "standard__Insights" application visibility from Admin.profile?

Tags: apex, profile

My team uses Eclipse for Salesforce development, and the ant-based Force migration tool for our builds.

We've all had our orgs for a while, but a teammate recently created a new org.  When we pushed to this org, we got an error that there is no "standard__Insights" app, which has an applicationVisibilities entry in our Admin.profile file.  We got rid of that entry and pushing to the new org now works.

Unfortunately, on our older orgs (which must still have the standard__Insights app), when we push from Eclipse, the standard__Insights app gets added back into Admin.profile.

When I go into my org and edit the System Administrator profile, I can't find "standard__Insights" anywhere.

I also can't find it under setup/create/Apps either.

How can I remove this so it doesn't keep popping up when I save to SF?

Answer (score 0):

standard__Insights is nothing but Wave Analytics. You will have the below components added when Analytics Cloud is provisioned:

Standard__Insights.App and 
Analytics Cloud Integration User.

Metadata of the app in profile.xml would be
[each set of privileges]

```
<ApplicationVisibilities> 
<Application> Standard__Insights </ Application> 
<Visible> False </ Visible> 
</ ApplicationVisibilities>
```

[ each profile]

```
<ApplicationVisibilities> 
<application> Standard__Insights </ application> 
<Default> False </ Default> 
<Visible> True </ Visible> 
</ ApplicationVisibilities>
```

[application menu (AppSwitcher.appMenu)]

```
<AppMenuItems> 
<Name> Standard__Insights </ Name> 
<Type> CustomApplication </ Type> 
</ AppMenuItems>
```

[new component]

```
Standard__Insights.App 
Analytics Cloud Integration User.
```

You can make desired changes to the xml depending on your source/destination.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my question is not how to manage Analytics Cloud / Wave Analytics, but how to delete it.  Is it possible?